# Removing images from Android Webview?

Tags: android, html, parsing, webview, tags

I have an Android Webview where I load HTML into using loadDataWithBaseURL, some of my images are displayed a "?" as if the image is missing. I had trouble fixing that so I'm now attempting to remove images altogether. I tried to use:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + "document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.display = 'none'; " + "})()");
```

But it didn't work, I'm struggling to think of another solution. The HTML code producing the images is formatted like so:

```
<img name="StartDate" src="images/calendar.gif" onclick="displayDatePicker('StartDate',false,'dmy','-')" alt="Press for a date picker" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
```